# Lost license out of state need to fly soon

Tags: air-travel, paperwork, domestic-travel, identity-cards

So I have a trip planned to Seattle, WA from Rochester, NY this weekend. However, today I went to buy pseudoephedrine and discovered that I have lost my license somewhere. I have retraced all of my steps, but I cannot find it. However, I am in Rochester for school and my home state in NJ. I do have a passport, but the problem is that it was issued in 2012 and I look very different from the photo since I was only 16 when it was taken. I also have an expired copy of my license, with a much more accurate photo and all of the same information. Every time I've been to the Rochester airport, TSA has been much more strict than what I'm used to at Newark. Do you think I will have a problem getting through airport security?

I have little faith in the NJ DMV to ship a new license to Rochester in time for my flight and this trip is an extremely important opportunity for my professional development.

Comment: Everyone knows that a five-year-old photo of a 21-year-old will look like a 16-year-old.  That said, I have no experience with the TSA security in Rochester.

Comment: A passport should be fine. It’s valid, so who cares if you look a bit different, that’s normal. Consider taht if you travel ourside the US, the passport is the only thing they’d ever see.

Comment: We discussed, in a different context, passport photos and likeliness https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/82142/4188 here and in general the old adage also commented there applies: When you look like your passport photo, it's time to go home.  - No one looks like their passport photo. As a dual citizen, I have two passports and one of them looks like a ravaged skeleton the other round like a pumpkin and they are supposedly both me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a passport as identification for travel on airline flights almost anywhere in the world.  I would take your expired driver's license and explain your situation to the TSA officer if questioned.  Offer it if (s)he doubts that it's you in the passport.